# Make it easier & quicker to find relevant Stack Exchange site with tooltips

Tags: feature-request, site-recommendation, information-display, navigation

When browsing https://stackexchange.com/sites you have to click on a tab in order to see what that particular site relates to. While in many cases it's obvious, in many others it isn't (eg. Stack Overflow, Super User and Arqade).

Ideally, you would be able to view this brief description of the purpose of the site when hovering over each tab with your mouse cursor.

I really like your site, but if I'm going to use it regularly, this is almost a deal-breaker: I, like so many people, value time-saving features above all else. I really think this will benefit all your users, including seasoned users, and will benefit you by increasing the popularity of your site.

Comment: I guess you are specifically referring to the [grid version](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid). Note that when you change it to [list view](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic), it shows the user target of those sites. However, I guess it's a good idea to show that as tooltip on grid view!

Comment: Oh that's great to know, thanks Andrew T.! That literally resolves the issue! Changing to list view now :)